# Why CALayer's dynamic @property can invoke setter method？

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer

I test @dynamic in NSObject and CALayer,When DynamicTest class inherits NSObject, run

> test.title = @"title";

it crashed because there is no setter/getter method in the DynamicTest class.

```
@interface DynamicTest : NSObject

@property NSString *title;

@end

@implementation DynamicTest
@dynamic title;

@end

DynamicTest *test = [[DynamicTest alloc] init];
test.title = @"title";//crashed
```

but When DynamicTest class inherits CALayer, it works!,

```
@interface DynamicTest : CALayer

@property NSString *title;

@end

@implementation DynamicTest
@dynamic title;

@end

DynamicTest *test = [[DynamicTest alloc] init];
test.title = @"title";//it works!
```

I knew that CALayer has do something for this，I want to know the detail，Looking forward to your help，thank you！

Answer (score 2):

Read the [Core Animation Programming Guide: Key-Value Coding Extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Key-ValueCodingExtensions/Key-ValueCodingExtensions.html):

> The `CAAnimation` and `CALayer` classes are key-value coding compliant container classes, which means that you can set values for arbitrary keys. Even if the key `someKey` is not a declared property of the `CALayer` class, you can still set a value for it as follows:
>
> ```
> [theLayer setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:50] forKey:@"someKey"];
> ```

Although it’s not explicitly stated, this support extends to providing dynamic accessors.

Comment: Do you know that why animating custom Layer properties should make properties as @dynamic?